# Vulkan vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges explanation

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

[From the Vulkan doc](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges.html) it says "vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges guarantees that device writes to the memory ranges described by pMemoryRanges, which have been made available to the host memory domain using the VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT and VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT access types, are made visible to the host."

I wonder what command uses VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT and VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT to do the memory domain operation to make the write to the device domain available also available to the host domain? Or does it mean vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges will do the device domain to host domain operation itself?
I know vkQueueSubmit will internally do a host domain to device domain operation after we do a vkflushmappedmemoryranges , but what command does the opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with anything else in Vulkan, you have to establish a barrier between the write and the read to make the write available to the reader. The fact that the read is on the host does not change this fact; it merely changes how you have to go about creating that barrier.

You need to use a memory barrier after the device writes to provide host availability through the `VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT`. This is typically done by using a pipeline barrier with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` as the destination scope.

However, the CPU cannot act on any of this until it has synchronized in some way with that barrier. So it needs to wait on an event set after the barrier or the fence submitted with the whole queue submit operation. Note that the event itself cannot *itself* contain the barrier; the barrier must happen before the event is set.

Comment: Thank you Nicol! Could you give me an example of calling vkCmdPipelineBarrier with VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT and VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT please? 

Because based on this https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdPipelineBarrier.html
it says "VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT specifies a pseudo-stage indicating execution on the host of reads/writes of device memory. This stage is not invoked by ****any commands recorded in a command buffer***". However vkCmdPipelineBarrier is indeed a command buffer command which seems to not be eligible due to the what the doc says

Comment: @AnningWuwang: The pipeline stage VERTEX_SHADER is invoked by all `vkCmdDraw*` calls. But the pipeline stage COMPUTE_SHADER` is not invoked by those calls. It is invoked by `vkCmdDispatch*` calls, which do not invoke vertex shaders. Host operations are not invoked by any *commands* in the exact same way that vertex shaders are not invoked by `vkCmdDispatch` commands. The stage can still "happen", just not by invoking command buffer commands.

Comment: Thanks Nicol. To me vkCmdDraw*, vkCmdDispatch, and vkCmdPipelineBarrier all of them are command buffer commands, because all their names contain "Cmd" in them, and their first function parameter is a VkCommandBuffer as well, which mean they are all commands that are to be recorded in a command buffer. This contradicts the doc that says "This stage is not invoked by any commands recorded in a command buffer"
So I'm just literally confused by this. But I understand what you said. your statement sounds to me like one which cannot be literally derived from the doc's statement...

Comment: So it will feel correct to me if the doc says "This stage is not invoked by any commands except vkCmdPipelineBarrier recorded in a command buffer"

Comment: @AnningWuwang: `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` does not "invoke" *any* stages whatsoever. It interacts with how states execute and what is visible between them, but it does not actually cause any operations within those stages. To "invoke", for example, a vertex shader, means to execute some number of vertex shader instances. `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` does not do that.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! This "invoke" explanation makes sense now!

Comment: Hi Nicol, I have another question that may be off topic to this thread, but I really appreciate your vulkan knowledge, so I wonder if you could help me here instead? I read some code example about copying images between cpu&gpu using VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT.  (For simplicity I'll use phsuedo code below) For cpu->gpu It is like 1. vkcmdbarrier(host_write, transfer_read, src_img), 2. vkcmdcopyimage(src_img, dst_img)
For gpu->cpu it is like 1. vkcmdcopyimage(src_img, dst_img) 2. vkcmdbarrier(transfer_write, host_read, src_img).

Comment: I can understand the cpu->gpu part, as we need to use the barrier to make the src_img visible to gpu, so we do the barrier first, then copy src_img to dst_img.
But for gpu->cpu, it does the copy first and then the barrier later. I wonder without using the barrier to make the src_img visible to the host first, how can the image copy succeed?
FYI, the code example is from here, https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xf064d23ec4332e7951809e5112a592758b3c2c71a4560a9e77da0176b1a9193a
Please refer to function CopyToImage and function CopyFromImage

Comment: @AnningWuwang: "*I wonder if you could help me here instead?*" This is not a forum; it's a Q&A site. Comments are for asking about details for a question/answer. If you have a new question, you should post that *as a question*.

Comment: Sure, I will create another thread with this question, it'd be fab if you could help me there please!